# Why $\lambda(23)=22$, when $2^{11}\equiv 1 \pmod {23}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

According to wikipedia, the Carmichael function, $\lambda(n)$ is defined as the smallest positive integer $m$ for which:
$$a^m\equiv 1\pmod n$$
for coprime $a$ and $n$. Now choose $a=2, n=23$. We get that $\lambda(23)=22$ is the smallest possible $m$ such that:
$$2^m\equiv 1\pmod {23}$$
But according to my calculations: $2^{11}=2048\equiv 1\pmod {23}$ and $11<22$.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It must be $a^m\equiv 1\pmod n$ for every integer $a$ that is coprime to $n.$

Comment: @mfl yeah, just found that out too.

Comment: Basically, $2$ is not a primitive root modulo $23$. In fact, by this calculation, it must be a quadratic residue mod $23$. And the value of $a$ such that $ a^2 \equiv 2 \bmod 23$ is not hard to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. The thing is that $\lambda(n)$ is the smallest positive value such that:
$$a^m\equiv 1 \pmod n$$
for **every** coprime $a$ and $n$. My example doesn't hold when $a=5$.